# Web Table Scrapping: Find adjacent cell value from web table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

On this website https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/, I am able to find the name of the city using this XPath `//table/tbody/tr[1]//a[text()='Accra']` keeping this XPath as pivot/reference I want to find out its time. So I tried this XPath `//table/tbody/tr[1]//a[text()='Accra']/../following::td[@class='rbi']` but it is giving XPath of other elements.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get a unique Xpath of Time in reference to the city name?
So that I can parametrize the XPath with row number and city name only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use element numbers?

```
//table/tbody/tr[1]//a[text()='Accra']/..//following-sibling::td[1]
//table/tbody/tr[1]//a[text()='Casablanca']/..//following-sibling::td[1]
//table/tbody/tr[4]//a[text()='Dallas']/..//following-sibling::td[1]
...
```

Using `class` property is not suitable in your case. You just should use `1` for first element.